# Inserting code at compile time or any alternative solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to make my code cleaner. All my views have a lot of this:

```
@Html.LabelFor(p => p.something)
@Html.EditorFor(p => p.something)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(p => p.something)
```

So what I have done is define a inline layout in EVERY view:

```
@helper EditorBlock(Expression<Func< MyModel, string>>   stringExp=null,
        Expression<Func< MyModel,   bool>>     boolExp=null,

@if     (stringExp!= null) {
   @Html.LabelFor(stringExp)
   @Html.EditorFor(stringExp)
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(stringExp)  
}
else if (boolExp!= null) {
   @Html.LabelFor(boolExp)
   @Html.EditorFor(boolExp)
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(boolExp)
}
```

Take in account that this inline function is model-dependenting (see "MyModel"). Plus I have needed to define stringExp and boolExp parameters for my model (and sometimes even extra intExp)...

With this I can leave my code like this:

```
@EditorBlock(p => p.something) 
@EditorBlock(p => p.foo)
@EditorBlock(p => p.bar)...
```

Which helps a lot when I need to apply div elements and styles to the views

The problem is that I need to define this inline function in every view. Again, the problem is that LabelFor, EditorFor, ValidationMessageFor... needs a lambda expression at compile time... they can't have the lambda expression in a variable neither anything determined programmatically.

What I would like to do is be able to extract EditorBlock to an external file, this would save me of "copy and paste", and adapt this function in EVERY file (again: the problem is that this function is model and parameter dependenting)... and I have no clue of which approach could help me. If I would be able to define a macro fucntion I think I could handle it, but I have seen that macro functions are not supported on c#. Could someone give me some advice or any other approach?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create an extension method. Something similar to this: <sup><sub>(Not tested)</sub></sup>

```
public static MvcHtmlString BlockFor<TModel, TValue>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> html,
    Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
{
    var label = html.LabelFor(expression);
    var editor = html.EditorFor(expression);
    var validator = html.ValidationMessageFor(expression);

    return MvcHtmlString.Create("" + label + editor + validator);
}
```

Which you then use like:

```
@Html.BlockFor(model => model.Whatever)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! this saved my day...I needed to change a few things:

     var label = LabelExtensions.LabelFor(html, expression);
     var editor = EditorExtensions.EditorFor(html, expression); but finally it worked. Really grateful

Comment: Weird. Those extension methods should have worked out the box (I *did* check it compiled) . Definitely had the right namespaces imported?

Comment: Sorry, you are right, I dont know what I did first time, but I have it checked again and it works as you wrote. Thanks again